# How to add user data from Firebase Authentication into Firebase Realtime Database right after signing in the user?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use Firebase's Realtime Database to implement [Firechat](https://firechat.firebaseapp.com/docs/). In the example code taken from the [Github repository](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firechat/blob/master/examples/anonymous/index.html), it uses Firebase Realtime Database to store users' data (email and UID). I've already successfully implemented Firebase's user authentication system in my web project, and I thought it'd be a good idea to use Firechat and get the users from their Firebase UID.

The problem is, I don't see any data in the Firebase's RTDB when I sign a user in.

I've already added the relevant CDN's into the user registration page. I've defined simple rules as follows:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Here's the JavaScript code (I've already instantiated Firebase with the API key from the console):

```
new Vue ({
    el: '#logreg',
    data: {
        email: null,
        password: '',
        signedUp: false,
        userUID: '',
        errorCode: '',
        errorMessageFlag: false,
    },

    methods: {
        register () {
            firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION).then(() => {
                firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password).then((signedUp) => {
                    this.signedUp = true;

                    firebase.database().ref('users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).set({
                        userUID: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
                        email: firebase.auth().currentUser.email,
                    });
                })
            });
        },
    },
})
```

I haven't changed anything in the Firechat's example code, except adding the Firebase API configs.

Comment: If you simply do `register () { firebase.database().set(true); }`, does that write anything to the database?

Comment: What does the web console log say?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, The browser console now shows an error `TypeError: firebase.database(...).set is not a function`. Before that, there was no error in the browser console.

Comment: You might want to run in a debugger and see if `firebase` and `firebase.database()` are loaded correctly.